# Amazon pricing - transfer between EC2, EBS and S3

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I have read quite a bit on amazon and the pricing details for EC2, EBS and S3 but i still have a few questions:

If i understand correctly, traffic between EC2 instances isn't billed.

- Is the data transfer between an EC2 instance and S3 still accounted for? (as if i was accessing S3 from another server)
- How about traffic - and requests - from EBS snapshots? (i assume here disk space is billed in S3 according to the snapshot size)

Comment: @MarkHenderson: How could you possibly think that these questions are too localized?

Comment: it is only relevant to a small geographic area, **a specific moment in time**...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any traffic between services is billed.

Any traffic between different tiers of EC2 instances is billed.

Disk space and IO is billed for S3 and snaps.

Answer (score 10):

Please look at http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#pricing

Traffic between services is free if they are in the same region (US or EU).  This means that traffic between EC2 in the US and S3 in the US is free.

Similarly, all traffic between instances in the same region is free.

Comment: And between zones as well?

Comment: @djangofan, from http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/:
"There is no Data Transfer charge between Amazon EC2 and other Amazon Web Services within the same region (i.e. between Amazon EC2 US West and Amazon S3 in US West). Data transferred between Amazon EC2 instances located in different Availability Zones in the same Region will be charged Regional Data Transfer. Data transferred between AWS services in different regions will be charged as Internet Data Transfer on both sides of the transfer."